# Writing a C# program for class and I cannot figure out where it is going wrong

Tags: c#

Ok so I am writing this program for class but when I run it the results only work if the inputted score is below 800, it also will not post the response if an invalid number is entered, can someone please help me. Here is the code I wrote:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string firstName, lastName, grade;
        double score, percent;
        //inputs
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name");
        firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your last name:");
        lastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Please enter a score: ");
        score = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        //processes
        if (score < 0 || score > 1000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Score");
        }
        else
        {
            percent = score / 1000;
            if (percent >= .9)
            {
                grade = "A";
            }
            else
            {
                if (percent >= .8)
                {
                    grade = "B";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (percent >= .7)
                    {
                        grade = "C";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (percent >= .6)
                        {
                            grade = "D";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            grade = "F";
                        }
                    }
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n========================================================");
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Your precentage is " + percent.ToString("P"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Your letter grade is: " + grade);
                }
            }
        }
     Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Do you know how to set a break point and step through the program line by line to see what's failing? Literally genuinely curious, not trying to shame or be rude.

Comment: @MarkC. I suspect most people learn that / figure that out way, way too late.

Comment: Very true. Learning to debug and step through code is similar to the old adage "a picture is worth a thousand words".  It is a LOT easier to spot logic problems when you can actually see what is happening at each step of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are kind of not using `if else if else` correctly. You want to test for each letter grade appropriately. Each test for the grade is a `if => else if`.. If you don't get an A, do you get a B? Do you get a C? Do you get a D, or do you get an F - and you need to nest the logic appropriately. I'll also note that the end of your logical container blocks was incorrect. You want to calculate the logic and then execute the `WriteLine();`.. Keep it all separate.

```
 //processes
            if (score < 0 || score > 1000)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Score");
            }
            else
            {
                percent = score/1000;

                if (percent >= .9)
                {
                    grade = "A";
                }
                else if (percent >= .8)
                {
                    grade = "B";
                }
                else if (percent >= .7)
                {
                    grade = "C";
                }
                else if (percent >= .6)
                {
                    grade = "D";
                }
                else
                {
                    grade = "F";
                }
```

Comment: You should probably get rid of the superfluous B.

Answer (score 2):

Your output statements are within the else block that deals only with grades `C`, `D` and `F`. That's why a `B` or better (being `0.8+`) will not output anything.

You should move those statements to *after* the complete block that calculates the grade, something like:

```
if (score < 0 || score > 1000) {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Score");
} else {
    percent = score / 1000;
    if (percent >= .9) {
        grade = "A";
    } else {
        if (percent >= .8) {
            grade = "B";
        } else {
            if (percent >= .7) {
                grade = "C";
            } else {
                if (percent >= .6) {
                    grade = "D";
                } else {
                    grade = "F";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n========================================================");
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
    Console.WriteLine("Your precentage is " + percent.ToString("P"));
    Console.WriteLine("Your letter grade is: " + grade);
}
```

Or, my personal preference for readability:

```
if (score < 0 || score > 1000) {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Score");
} else {
    percent = score / 1000;

    if      (percent >= .9) grade = "A";
    else if (percent >= .8) grade = "B";
    else if (percent >= .7) grade = "C";
    else if (percent >= .6) grade = "D";
    else                    grade = "F";

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n========================================================");
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
    Console.WriteLine("Your precentage is " + percent.ToString("P"));
    Console.WriteLine("Your letter grade is: " + grade);
}
```

---

In terms of catching non-numeric input, you can replace the line:

```
    score = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

with:

```
try {
    score = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
} catch (FormatException e) {
    score = -1;
}
```

This will trap the entry of invalid data and force `score` to be valid but out of range in that case, which will then be caught by your later check for the `0..1000` range.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move you Console.WriteLine out on curly brace level. The Invalid number check will also work.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string firstName, lastName, grade;
        double score, percent;
        //inputs
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name");
        firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your last name:");
        lastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Please enter a score: ");

        score = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


        //processes
        if (score < 0 || score > 1000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Score");
        }
        else
        {
            percent = score / 1000;
            if (percent >= .9)
            {
                grade = "A";
            }
            else
            {
                if (percent >= .8)
                {
                    grade = "B";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (percent >= .7)
                    {
                        grade = "C";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (percent >= .6)
                        {
                            grade = "D";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            grade = "F";
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n========================================================");
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
                Console.WriteLine("Your precentage is " + percent.ToString("P"));
                Console.WriteLine("Your letter grade is: " + grade);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is poorly written but it is correct. Just move the console write codes below out of the else bracket.

```
if (percent >= .9)
{
    grade = "A";
}
else
{
...... your other code
}
//Bring these down here. Out of the else.
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
Console.WriteLine("\n\n========================================================");
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName);
Console.WriteLine("Your precentage is " + percent.ToString("P"));
Console.WriteLine("Your letter grade is: " + grade);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Console.WriteLine calls are in the code block that only executes if percent is less than 0.8. If you cut all of those WriteLine lines and paste them two lines down so that there is only one curly brace between the WriteLines and the final ReadLine it should work.